# Generate uniformly distributed points in n-dimensional sphere

Tags: geometry, density-function, spheres, dimension-theory-analysis

I have an n-dimensional space and I am trying to dynamically allocate points in the space as I need them.

Every time I search for radius nearest neighbours for point X, I locate the points inside the n sphere of center X and radius R. if the number of neighbours is less than N I want to generate points so that the new points and the existing points inside the sphere of center X are all uniformly distributed.

In other words I want a measure of density of regions of the n sphere and allocate new points in the regions that are less dense.

Any help on this?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly, but any easy answer to your title question is to draw vector from the standard gaussian and then normalize. What is the relation between the different points? Independent?

Comment: @AreaMan when the sphere has zero points inside of it, then I can do what you suggested and uniformly distribute points inside the sphere. But if I already have few points that were generated from a different sphere that overlaps with this one, then if I uniformly distribute points inside this sphere the overlapping part will be more dense. I want to generate points in the less dense area of the sphere.

Comment: I'm still not totally sure of your set up, but maybe you can do some kind of rejection sampling? Can you clarify what sort of uniformity you want? What is the measure on the set of $N$ points in the ball? Independently uniform? Something else?

Comment: The space is a memory, it is called Sparse Ditributed Memory (it’s a content addressable memory). The idea is instead of having a full memory over all the space (every dimension has a range) you create Hard Locations uniformly distributed over the space. The hard location has an address in space (n dimensional vector) and some data that we store in. To read or write from the memory address X, you find all the hard location within radius R from X and from their data you read from the memory or write to these hard locations.

Comment: But instead of generating all the hard locations over the full space at the beginning (even without storing any data) I want to dynamically allocate hard location as I need them. And that happens when I’m writing data. So when I’m writing address X, I find all the hard locations within radius R of point X. If the number of these hard locations is less than N (a parameter I choose) then I want allocate hard locations inside this area (the access sphere of center X and radius R).

Comment: The problem is that other access spheres can overlap, and if I just generate points uniformly random Inside the sphere I am accessing, then that overlap can have denser hard locations relative to the whole space where hard locations exist. In other words If I have a circle and there are 2 points in the top right part of the circle, I want to generate 2 points in the top left, 2 points in the bottom right and 2 points in the bottom left. But in n dimensions.